# want to print the next line also after matching the string

Tags: python, regex, match, newline, string-matching

I have a string

```
output = '''Gateway of last resort is not set

      10.0.1.0/8 is variably subnetted, 4 subnets, 2 masks
C        10.1.0.0/24 is directly connected, Ethernet1/0
L        10.1.0.1/32 is directly connected, Ethernet0/0
C        10.2.0.0/24 is directly connected, Ethernet0/1
L        19.18.2.1/32 is directly connected, Serial2/1
O     19.18.3.0/20 [110/128] via 19.18.2.2, 00:00:50, Serial1/1
                     [110/128] via 19.18.1.2, 00:00:50, Serial1/0

O     12.18.3.1/20 [110/128] via 19.18.2.2, 00:00:50, Serial1/1
                     [110/128] via 19.18.1.2, 00:00:50, Serial1/0

O     12.18.1.0/20 [110/128] via 19.18.2.2, 00:00:50, Serial0/1
                     [110/128] via 19.18.1.2, 00:00:50, Serial0/0'''
```

From this string I am matching for `O`  and printing the complete line using:

```
regex = re.findall("O\s+(?P<O>\w+.\w+.\w+.\w+.*)", output, re.M)
```

It gives me output as:

```
['19.18.3.0/20 [110/128] via 19.18.2.2, 00:00:50, Serial1/1', '12.18.3.1/20 [110/128] via 19.18.2.2, 00:00:50, Serial1/1', '12.18.1.0/20 [110/128] via 19.18.2.2, 00:00:50, Serial0/1']
```

But I want to print these lines also along with the above output.

```
[110/128] via 19.18.1.2, 00:00:50, Serial1/0,  [110/128] via 19.18.1.2, 00:00:50, Serial1/0, [110/128] via 19.18.1.2, 00:00:50, Serial0/0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can opt to match an optional line that starts with spaces after the pattern:

```
O\s+(?P<O>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+.*(?:[\r\n]+[^\S\r\n]+.*)?)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kH2rE1/2)

Updated pattern details: `(?:[\r\n]+[^\S\r\n]+.*)?` is an optional non-capturing group (`(?:...)?`) that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of

- `[\r\n]+` - one or more CR/LF symbols (to only match one, use `(?:\r?\n|\r|\n)`)
- `[^\S\r\n]+` - 1 or more symbols other than non-whitespace and CR/LFs (thus, it matches horizontal whitespace only
- `.*` - the rest of the line (`.` does not match a newline by default without DOTALL mode).

Also, I suggest escaping the `.` to match literal dots inside the IP address, and replace `\w` with `\d` to match only digits.

If the first `O`  appears at the beginning of a line, add `^` before it for safety.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, And yes the command worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
regex = re.findall("(?s)O\s+(?P<O>\w+.\w+.\w+.\w+.*)", output, re.M)
```

I add `(?s)` for adding `s` flag to also match whitespaces.

Comment: [This solution does not match individual entries](https://regex101.com/r/nE4yC9/1).